# Add-Migration keeps adding blank 'Up' and 'Down' functions in Init.cs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to do a code-first API with accepts the classes that I've created in my FourPointImport.Data project, based on their using the Import base class.

This worked in EF 5.0, but now doesn't in 6.0.  It continuously shows:

> Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'FourPointImport.Web'...
> No design-time services were found.>

For .Web and .Data projects.I've tried the solutions on StackOverflow and none of them have corrected the problem.

Has anyone seen this before?  I've included my APIDBContext class, the design time factory, the base class and the class it's inherited from below.  The classes I want to add are similar to Import, except their preceded with

> [Table("BillingDetail", Schema = "dbo")]>

public class ApiDbContext:DbContext
{
protected IConfiguration _configuration;

```
    public ApiDbContext()
    {
        _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "@\appsettings.json").Build();
    }
    public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected virtual IList<Assembly> Assemblies
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<Assembly>() { Assembly.Load("FourPointImport.Data") };
        }
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var assembly in Assemblies)
        {
            var classes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(s => s.GetInterfaces().Any(_interface => _interface.Equals(typeof(Import))
                && s.IsClass && s.IsPublic));
            foreach (var classType in classes)
            {
                var entityType = modelBuilder.Entity(classType);
                var genericMethod = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity").MakeGenericMethod(classType);
                genericMethod.Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
            }

        }
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
    {
        if (!builder.IsConfigured || _configuration==null)
        {
            _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();
        }
        //now set the database connection
        if (_configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"] != null)
            builder.UseSqlServer(_configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
    }
}
public class DesignTimeDbContext : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApiDbContext>
{
    IConfiguration _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
    
    public ApiDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApiDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        return new ApiDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
public class Import : IImport
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool Archive { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreateOn { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SuspenseMaster>().Property(x => x.id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SuspenseMaster>().Property(x => x.Archive);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SuspenseMaster>().Property(x => x.CreateOn);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SuspenseMaster>().Property(x => x.LastUpdated);
    }
}
   public interface IImport
{
    int id { get; set; }
    bool Archive { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset CreateOn { get; set; }
    DateTimeOffset LastUpdated { get; set; }

    public static void OnModelCreating<TEntity>(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        where TEntity :class, IImport
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().HasKey(entity => entity.id).HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", "SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy:IdentityColumn");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use a db context from another project?

Comment: Did you create all the ```DbSet<>``` for all models in the context ?

Comment: @JerdineSabio - yes, I am.

Comment: @DarkkL No, I want to cycle through all of the models, pick the ones with the Import base, and then add them to context

Answer (score 0):

After working on this all day, I found that the way that I was sorting the assembly was precluding all of the classes, and rewrote it like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            try
            {
                var classes = assembly.GetTypes()
                    .Where(type => type.IsClass && type.IsPublic && (type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType == typeof(Import)) && type.IsPublic && !type.IsAbstract)
                    .ToList();
                foreach (var classType in classes)
                {
                    var onModelCreatingMethod = classType.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "OnModelCreating" && x.IsStatic);
                    if (onModelCreatingMethod != null)
                        onModelCreatingMethod.Invoke(classType, new object[] { modelBuilder });
                    if (classType.BaseType == null || classType.BaseType != typeof(Import))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var baseOnModelCreatingMethod = classType.BaseType.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "onmodelcreating" && x.IsStatic);
                    if (baseOnModelCreatingMethod == null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    baseOnModelCreatingMethod.Invoke(typeof(Import), new object[] { modelBuilder });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    
}
```

What this does is to find all of the classes in my Data project (containing the ApiDbContext class) which use the "Import" base class, are public and aren't abstract and makes sure tget have a static 'onModelCreating' function, then adds them to the migration, which I can then update them to the database.  This means that I don't have to make changes to ApiDbContext if I add or remove tables.

Comment: You're defining each type ... for each type? Your inner loop is running `O(n^2)` times?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman no - it checks every class in both assemblies.  If you put a 'Console.WriteLine' statement in there, you can see what it finds and that it doesn't check the same thing twice.

Comment: You have two variables called `type` there. One in the `foreach` loop, one in the `.Where()` lambda. It loos like the `foreach` loop variable isn't used, and the `foreach` only seems to exist to cause your inner loop to execute multiple times.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman You are right - I don't know how that extra line got into my example and not into my code.  I corrected the code.

Thank you very much!